# PROBLEMAS CON ENVIAR INPUT ARRAY forms

Tags: php, html, webforms

Deseo enviar un formulario:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process.php" charset="utf-8"> 
<input type='file' name="documentos[]" id="0"  required/>
</form>
```

Al momento de enviar, en la url me aparece **documentos%5B0%5D=business.png** o si utilizo acentos también envia de forma incorrecta.
el encabezado lo tengo así

```
<meta  http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
```

Alguna sugerencia? desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: cual es el problema? no envia la imagen?

Comment: consulto: que quieres exactamente que haga el codigo..?

Comment: No envía el array correctamente, los acentos y "ñ" no salen, en sus lugares aparecen cualquier caracter. Aclaro que mi pagina está configurada en UTF-8 pero aún así me falla el envío del formulario

Comment: Específicamente, en lugar del corchete de "documentos[]" me envía como documentos%5B%5D=imagen.png